# When using the Python Image Library, does open() immediately decompress the image file?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, timing, compression

**Short question**

When using the Python Image Library, does `open()` immediately decompress the image file?

**Details**

I would like to measure the decompression time of compressed images (jpeg, png...), as I read that it's supposed to be a good measure of an image's "complexity" (a blank image will be decompressed quickly, and so will a purely random image, since it will not have been compressed at all, so the most "interesting" images are supposed to have the longest decompression time).  So I wrote the following python program:

```
# complexity.py
from PIL import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO
import time
import sys

def mesure_complexity(image_path, iterations = 10000):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    data_io = StringIO(data)

    t1 = time.time()
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        data_io.seek(0)
        Image.open(data_io, "r")
    t2 = time.time()
    return t2 - t1

def main():
    for filepath in sys.argv[1:]:
        print filepath, mesure_complexity(filepath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It can be used like this:

```
#python complexity.py blank.jpg blackandwhitelogo.jpg trees.jpg random.jpg
blank.jpg 1.66653203964
blackandwhitelogo.jpg 1.33399987221
trees.jpg 1.62251782417
random.jpg 0.967066049576
```

As you can see, I'm not getting the expected results at all, especially for the blank.jpg file: it should be the one with the lowest "complexity" (quickest decompression time).  So either the article I read is utterly wrong (I really doubt it, it was a serious scientific article), or PIL is not doing what I think it's doing.  Maybe the actual conversion to a bitmap is done lazily, when it's actually needed?  But then why would the `open` delays differ?  The smallest jpg file is of course the blank image, and the largest is the random image.  This really does not make sense.

Note 1: when running the program multiple times, I get roughly the same results: the results are absurd, but stable.  ;-)

Note 2: all images have the same size (width x height).

**Edit**

I just tried with png images instead of jpeg, and now everything behaves as expected.  Cool! I just sorted about 50 images by complexity, and they *do* look more and more "complex".  I checked the article (BTW, it's an article by Jean-Paul Delahaye in 'Pour la Science', April 2013): the author actually mentions that he used only loss-less compression algorithms.  So I guess the answer is that `open` *does* decompress the image, but my program did not work because I should have used images compressed with loss-less algorithms only (png, but not jpeg).

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got it sorted out. Anyway, the `open()` method is indeed a lazy operation – as stated in the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open), to ensure that the image will be loaded, use `image.load()`, as this will actually force PIL / Pillow to interpret the image data (which is also stated in the linked documentation).

Comment: The link no longer works. You might want to update the answer. Also provide links to why image.load() should work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I changed it.